# why toLowerCase is not working in my code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, case-sensitive

In my case i am trying to filter the result from firebase data based on the inputs given by the user. Since firebase is case sensitive iam trying to convert the `String Course`  into lowercase at both ends inorder to overcome the case sensitivity in the following code.

```
    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                CollegeFilterDetails models=data.getValue(CollegeFilterDetails.class);





                  if(   (ClgType.equals("") || ClgType.equals(models.getType()))
                        &&(University.equals("")||University.equals(models.getUniversity()))
                        &&(Course.equals("")||Course.equals(models.getCourse().toLowerCase()))
                        &&(State.equals("")||State.equals(models.getState()))
                        &&(District.equals("") || District.equals(models.getDistrict()))

                        ){


                    filteredList.add(new ObjectModel(models.getName(),models.getPlace(),models.getImage()));
                    flag++;

                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "found "+flag+" results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This throws the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference` when i add `toLowerCase()` to the Course.

Comment: Have you checked if your models.getCourse() returns a value?

Comment: Off course it returns value. Error when i added toLowerCase.